# How to merge the result from the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, merge, union

So the data i want to combine column C & D together because they have the same ID as column A

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | B | B |
| A | A | C | C |

And i want to look like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | B C | B C |

Comment: What if the two rows have different values in the column b?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use aggregation query like below (Test on MySQL 8.0):

```
select Column A, Column B, concat(Column C, Column D) from table group by Column A, Column B;
```

In MySQL 8.0, this query sql will not work as ERROR 1055 (42000): this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. So set sql_mode=‘’ for current session.

Comment: When i do this it show BB, earlier i try uing string_agg but it didnt detect distinct funstiion